# Is there a better way to store data from an API in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, user-interface

I'm developing the interface of a music web app , so i fetched data from an API and stored in state, all executed by one function , to be displayed on the interphase .The code is below :

```
/* function fetching the data*/
  function getUsChart() {
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '036795ec2amsh8c2b98ef8a502acp146724jsn6f3538b26522',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'shazam-core.p.rapidapi.com'
      }
    };
    
    fetch('https://shazam-core.p.rapidapi.com/v1/charts/genre-country?country_code=US&genre_code=HIP_HOP_RAP', options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => setUsHopChart(response))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
/*I stored it in state here*/
      setChartImg(usHopChart[1]?.images?.coverart)
  }
```

```
/*I displayed it here*/
             <img src={chartImg} className='chart-img rounded-3xl' alt='chart-image'/>
```

**The issue:**
After the function is executed , the data is fetched but not stored it in the state immediately until it's executed the second time. Hence causing this :
[image]

What can i do about this please?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to move the setChartImg inside

```js
  fetch('https://shazam-core.p.rapidapi.com/v1/charts/genre-country?country_code=US&genre_code=HIP_HOP_RAP', options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        setUsHopChart(response)
        setChartImg(response[1]?.images?.coverart)
    })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
/*I stored it in state here*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is jsx is rendered before the fetch process is done. So, it is the best approach to create a boolean loading state and initialize it with true, when it's value is true create a spinner or smth and make it false when promise returns the value.

For quick solution maybe you can do something like that:

```
{chartImg && <img src={chartImg} className='chart-img rounded-3xl' alt='chart-image'/>}
```

So what it does is when chartImg is defined (when you give it a value after promise resolves) it will render the jsx element, which was your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to fetch data faster and store it in the state. There is a way to that. I will give you an example

```
const commentsPromise = fetch('/get-comments');

const Comments = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const dataFetch = async () => {
      // just await the variable here
      const data = await (await commentsPromise).json();

      setState(data);
    };

    dataFetch();
  }, [url]);
}
```

In this example our fetch call basically “escapes” all React lifecycle and will be fired as soon as javascript is loaded on the page, before any of useEffect anywere are called.

Even before the very first request in the roop App component will be called. It will be fired, javascript will move on to other things to process, and the data will just sit there quietly until someone actually resolves it.